# Create table in KDB with columns from results

Tags: kdb

I'm trying to create a table in KDB where the columns are the results of a query.  For example , I have loaded in stock data and search for a given time window what prices the stock traded at.  I created a function 
getTrades[Sybmol; Date; StartTime; StopTime]

This will search through my database and return the prices that traded between the start and stop time.  So my results for Apple for a 30 second window might be:
527.10, 527.45, 527.60, 526.90 etc.

What I want to do is now create a table using xbar where I have rows of every second and columns of all the prices that trade in StartTime and StopTime.  I will then place an X in the column if the price traded in that 1 second.  I think I can handle most of this but the main thing I'm struggling with is converting the results I got above into the name of the table.  I'm also struggling with how to make it flexible so my table will have 5 columns in one scenario (5 prices traded) but 10 in another so essentially it varies depending on how many price levels traded in the window I'm searching.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The best and cleanest way to do programmatic selects is with the functional form of select.

from q for mortals,

```
    ?[t;c;b;a]
```

where t is a table, a is a dictionary of aggregates, b is a dictionary of groupbys and c is a list of constraints.

In other words, select a by b from t where c.

This will allow you to dynamically create a, which can be of arbitrary size.

You can find more information here:
http://code.kx.com/q4m3/9_Queries_q-sql/#912-functional-forms

Answer (score 2):

[Pivot Table](http://code.kx.com/q/cookbook/pivoting-tables/)

I think that pivot table will be suitable in this case. Using jgleeson example:

```
time         price
------------------
11:27:01.600 106
11:27:02.600 102
11:27:02.600 102
11:27:03.100 100
11:27:03.100 102
11:27:03.100 102
11:27:03.100 104
11:27:03.600 104
11:27:03.600 102
11:27:04.100 106
11:27:05.100 105
11:27:06.600 106
11:27:07.100 101
11:27:07.100 104
11:27:07.600 105
11:27:07.600 105
11:27:07.600 101

not null exec (exec `$string asc distinct price from s)#(`$string price)!price by time:1 xbar time.second from s:select from t where time within 11:27:00 11:27:30
```

and returns:

```
time    | 100 101 102 103 104 105 106
--------| ---------------------------
11:27:01| 0   0   0   0   0   0   1
11:27:02| 0   0   1   0   0   0   0
11:27:03| 1   0   1   0   1   0   0
11:27:04| 0   0   0   0   0   0   1
11:27:05| 0   0   0   0   0   1   0
11:27:06| 0   0   0   0   0   0   1
11:27:07| 0   1   0   0   1   1   0
```

It can support any numbers of unique prices.

Answer (score 1):

This looks a bit convoluted... but I think this might be what you're after.

Sample table t with time and price columns:

```
t:`time xasc([]time:100?(.z.T+500*til 100);price:100?(100 101 102 103 104 105 106))
```

This table should replicate what you get from the first step of your function call - "select time,price from trade where date=x, symbol=y, starttime=t1, endtime=t2".

To return the table in the format specified:

```
q) flip (`time,`$string[c])!flip {x,'y}[key a;]value a:{x in y}[c:asc distinct tt`price] each group (!) . reverse value flip tt:update time:time.second from t

time     100 101 102 103 104 105 106
------------------------------------
20:34:29 0   1   0   0   0   1   0
20:34:30 0   0   0   0   0   0   1
20:34:31 0   0   1   0   0   0   0
20:34:32 0   0   1   0   1   0   0
...
```

This has bools instead of X as bools are probably easier to work with.

Also please excuse the one-liner... If I get a chance I'll break it up and try to make it more readable.

Answer (score 0):

A more simplified version is :

```
q)t:`time xasc([] s:100#`s ; time:100?(.z.T+500*til 100);price:100?(100 101 102 103 104 105 106))

q)t1:update `$string price,isPrice:1b from t

q)p:(distinct asc t1`price)

q)exec p#(10b!"X ")@(price!isPrice) by time:1 xbar time.second from t1
time    | 100 101 102 103 104 105 106
--------| ---------------------------
20:39:00| X   X   X
20:39:01| X   X   X       X
20:39:02|     X
20:39:04| X
20:39:05|             X   X   X   X
```